# Movie in which a hero beats the villain in a first-person shooter?

Tags: story-identification

I need help identifying a movie - it might be a TV movie or mini-series - probably from 1995-2005.

The hero has a computer he speaks to (it has a female voice), and there is a terrorist who, I think, kidnaps a girl. I am only sure about the ending in which the hero beats the villain in a virtual reality game that looks like Half-Life (a first-person shooter) using the rocket launcher which he finds thanks to his computer.

I think I also recall a scene in which, after the bad guy kidnaps the girl (or maybe just tricks her or charms her), he licks two small things and connects them to her forehead in order to control this "super computer" with lots of power.  He probably needs some information from her.

Answer (score 7):

There are several standout possibilities. If any are the case we can edit this answer to highlight that. We'll leave the others too, because other people may have been searching for the other ones.

**[Gamer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamer_%28film%29)** - [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECoPbiGfjNw)

Is a movie about nano-tech controlled inmates who are the Player Characters in a game controlled by other people in a reality TV show. It is somewhat like the movie [The Running Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Running_Man_%28film%29), and has the kidnapping/terrorist angle along with the idea of First Person Shooters.

However, it lacks this licking scene and doesn't take place in virtual reality.

**[Doom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doom_%28film%29)** - [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-NjsSrD2uG4)

Is a game-turned movie starring the Rock. It wasn't all that great, but the final scenes feature a First Person Shooter view exactly like you describe. However, it too isn't in virtual reality, and it doesn't feature a kidnapping or terrorist plot.

**[The Lawnmower Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lawnmower_Man_%28film%29)** - [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCxFGxqLsHE)

This movie is hard to describe... But it does feature virtual reality and segments that remind me of what you've described. There is also a sequel I've never seen.

Answer (score 4):

The movie you're looking for is a direct-to-TV (or so it looks) movie called **Max Knight: Ultra Spy**. They're definitely using the Half-Life engine and assets at the end of the movie, and you can find it broken into ten segments on YouTube.

Also, this question is a **[duplicate of this other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23895/identify-the-sci-fi-movie-based-on-max-steel-character/24117#24117)**.

Comment: Having played Black Mesa last week, I don't recall Half-Life looking completely like crap.

Comment: @cjc Nor do I remember GoldenEye 64 looking like crap. Still, revisit both games today and... well, there it is. Though a lot of it looks like they killed a substantial number of polygons in the model, the mobs and levels are uncannily similar.

Comment: @cjc Just re-watched **[this part](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ku5S2EEcgWw)** of the movie again and yeah, they're definitely using the models if nothing else. Got the HEV suit, some vortigaunts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like [Virtuosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtuosity) to me with Russell Crowe and Denzel Washington. Crowe plays a virtual reality AI that is based off of a serial killer. He enters the real world by tricking one of the programmers into thinking he's making an android clone of a hot girl AI. Ends with a showdown between Denzel and Crowe back inside cyberspace.