# Identify the sci-fi movie based on Max Steel character

Tags: story-identification

I remember a Live Action movie where a rich boy has a dual life: one as a rich guy and another as a hero. He has powers like invisibility through some kind of device and he is like an android. He has a super computer that has a girl's face which gives him his assignments.

I think the heroine has a similar face to super computer's face but I am not sure. But even super computer feels jealous of the heroine. The bad guy tried to use two girls to kill the hero. The girls use a poison capsule to kill people by kissing them, but they get killed by the Hero when the kiss effect gets reversed. There is a final fight sequence in a computer world (Virtual Reality) where the bad guy is killed by his own virus which he used to kill the hero in computer world.

I am sure its somehow related to [Max Steel.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Steel)

It may be a exact duplicate of [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/4296/sci-fi-movie-identification) question posted on `Movies and TV Beta`  but I am not sure, so I am posting it separately. I don't have any idea about release date but I watched it on HBO 6/7 years before in India.

(Some of my mentioned facts may be wrong but most of them are correct specially about invisibility, super computer and virtual computer world and Heroine's face similarity to computer's face).

Comment: Is this a Hollywood movie, a European/Russian movie, Bollywood? What year was it released? Was it shown theatrically, or straight-to-video or made-for-tv? Do you remember any of the character names?

Comment: It must be a hollywood english film , i watched it 6/7 years ago on HBO

Comment: That probably rules out the really bad direct-to-video stuff. Made no later than 2006.

Comment: Two questions. 1. Was it live action or animated? 2. Was the hero a cyborg or an android? Big difference, a cyborg is a human with robotic parts, whereas an android is a 100% robot made to look like a human.

Comment: @phoenixheart6 He is like a cyborg and its a live action movie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been driving me nuts ever since I saw your question the other day, since there are a lot of elements you spoke of that I've seen scattered in a lot of other works.

But I think my Google Fu has finally come through.

The movie in question is  **[Max Knight: Ultra Spy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Knight%3a_Ultra_Spy)**.

It's available in ten parts on YouTube with sub-par audio for your viewing pleasure.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Glad to be of service, and thank YOU for the challenge and the bounty! As well as an entertaining brief movie to watch.